# My panel-collapse not minimizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the View Map link the collapse show but when I click it again
it the div does not hide. I don't know what to do. I searched but its not working.

```
<a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">View Map</a>

<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <?php
        $map_url = $loc;
        $map_url = str_replace(" ", "+", $map_url);
    ?>
    <iframe width="350" height="250" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"  src="http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=<?=$map_url?>&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&t=v&hnear=<?=$map_url?>&z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: are there errors appearing in the dev console?

Comment: none . its just when I click view map again it doesn't hide

Comment: Can you please post the JQuery you're using to collapse the div?

Comment: its on the jquery.js